# List of Roman Imperial Coins ~0 CE/AD

Tags: ancient-rome, currency, numismatics

I'm trying to find a list of Roman Imperial Coins that were used around 0 CE/AD.

Most of the my searches turn up lots of shopping pages. After sorting through tons of listings, I can find lists that have Roman and Greek coins, but either the pages have no information to differentiate between Roman vs Greek, or they have no year placement. Most pages don't even match with information.

Anyone know a reliable site with Roman currency that dates around 0 CE?

Comment: There was no zero CE. You mean 1 CE?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are some great pages on roman coinage, e.g. the formidable [Roman Coins Database with more than 500 entries for roman early imperial coins](http://davy.potdevin.free.fr/Site/augustus.html). Additionally, Doug Smith's page on ancient coins has [some info on roman coins from the early empire](http://www.forumancientcoins.com/dougsmith/voc3.html).

Comment: Wow! Thanks. That's some really great information.